# Can a link other columns to a data set

Tags: database, google-sheets, dataset, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am pulling the first two columns from a database, the information is automatically populating in the gsheet. I have added column C and D for more information. This info in C and D is manually updated. How can I make all the rows static so that if information from A and B is removed or added from the database then C and D can be removed/added as well, and not shift incorrectly. Is this possible?

[image]

any formula I can use to say if this row is deleted, delete other rows in the different columns?

Comment: there are workarounds for this but to answer your question: no, its not possible unless you use some "common" element that will link your A:B columns to C:D columns

Comment: what are the workarounds? any formula I can use to say if this row is deleted, delete other rows in the same column?

Comment: no, there is no such formula. workaround would be to use scripts or as mentioned common element like unique id and the VLOOKUP C:D values based on it.